# Typescript: promise.then() still returning a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise

I have a function that returns a promise. I then want to get the value of said function, but when I call promise.then( result => result ) I'm still getting a promise.

The below code returns the following error:

`error: Type 'Promise<void | SunriseSunsetResultsType>' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

```
import {
    HebCalResponseType, 
    OpenweatherResponseType,
    SunriseSunsetResultsType,
    SunriseSunsetResponseType
} from "../src/app";

const lat: number = 40.8915;
const lng: number = -74.0119;
const date: string = "2012-11-09";
const url: string = `https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=${lat}&lng=${lng}&date=${date}&formatted=0`;

async function request(url: string): Promise<HebCalResponseType | OpenweatherResponseType | SunriseSunsetResponseType> {
    // Make a request of one of our three external apis
    const jsonResult: (HebCalResponseType | OpenweatherResponseType | SunriseSunsetResponseType) = (await fetch(url)).json();
    return jsonResult;
};

const promise: Promise<HebCalResponseType | OpenweatherResponseType | SunriseSunsetResponseType> = request(url); 
const msg: Promise<SunriseSunsetResultsType | void> =  promise
    .then(response => { (response as SunriseSunsetResponseType).results; }, 
        error => { throw `failed to load ${url} with error ${error}`; })
const test: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("source");
test.innerText = msg;
```

Comment: yes, the `Promise.then()` method does always return a `Promise`

Comment: If you say `const result = order_pizza.then(eat_pizza)` then the result *has* to be a promise. It can't be a full stomach, the pizza hasn't been delivered yet! Stuff inside `then` happens in the future when the promise is fulfilled. It can't happen now. We don't have time travel.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was missing an await.

```
const msg: ( SunriseSunsetResultsType | void ) =  await promise
    .then(response => { return (response as SunriseSunsetResponseType).results; }, 
        error => { throw `failed to load ${url} with error ${error}`; })
```

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was missing an `await`

```
const msg: ( SunriseSunsetResultsType | void ) =  await promise
    .then(response => { return (response as SunriseSunsetResponseType).results; }, 
        error => { throw `failed to load ${url} with error ${error}`; })
```